# Como limitar os resultado de uma query no DB4O?

Tags: sql, db4o

Como posso criar uma query que retorna um número limitado de resultados tal
como o `limit` do MySQL? Estou procurando na documentação e não estou achando.

Answer (score 1):

```
int fromIndex = 0 
int toIndex = 250;

List<MyObject> objetos = objectContainer.query(MyObject.class).subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
```

Comment: Não é o ideal ainda, pois objectContainer.query(MyObject.class) retorna todos os objetos e logo após o método subList apenas pega  determinada qtd que foi especificado